# How to color based on the last value on a time series line graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, label, facet-wrap

I have the following data (`mydata`):

```
structure(list(Provinsi = c("ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH"), Persenproposi = c(14.8500365764448, 15.5075939248601,  16.6821994408201, 20.0239808153477, 21.0322580645161, 22.1628838451268)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am plotting the Proporsi (y-axis) against Date (x-axis) for each provinces (using facet_wrap and geom_line).

```
mydata_ends <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(Provinsi) %>% 
  top_n(1, Date)

ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=Date,y=Proporsi, colors (if(Proporsi>=0.4){"RED"}, else if (Proporsi<=0.2){"GREEN"}), else {"Yellow"}) +
  xlab("Tanggal")+
  ylab("Proporsi Keterisian TT/Kasus Aktif")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accurracy=1))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = Proporsi), data = mydata_ends, size = 3)+
  facet_wrap(~Provinsi, ncol=5) +
  ggtitle("Proporsi KeterisianTT/Kasus Aktif") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family="Trebuchet MS", face="bold", size=20, hjust=0, color="#555555")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

I have been trying with the ggrepel and other coloring if functions but they didn't work.

Any help is appreciated, many thanks!

```
structure(list(Provinsi = c("ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", 
"ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", 
"ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", 
"ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "ACEH", "BALI", "BALI", 
"BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", 
"BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", 
"BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", "BALI", 
"BALI", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", 
"BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", 
"BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", 
"BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", "BANTEN", 
"BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", 
"BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", 
"BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", 
"BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", 
"BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "BENGKULU", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", 
"DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", 
"DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", 
"DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", 
"DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", 
"DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", 
"DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", 
"DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", 
"DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", 
"DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", 
"DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", 
"DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", 
"DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", 
"DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", 
"DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", "DKI JAKARTA", 
"DKI JAKARTA", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", 
"GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", 
"GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", 
"GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", 
"GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", 
"GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "GORONTALO", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", 
"JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", 
"JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", 
"JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", 
"JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAMBI", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", 
"JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", 
"JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", 
"JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", 
"JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", 
"JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA BARAT", "JAWA TENGAH", 
"JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", 
"JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", 
"JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", 
"JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", 
"JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TENGAH", 
"JAWA TENGAH", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", 
"JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", 
"JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", 
"JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", 
"JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", 
"JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR", "JAWA TIMUR"), Date = structure(c(1633392000, 
1633478400, 1633564800, 1633651200, 1633737600, 1633824000, 1633910400, 
1633996800, 1634083200, 1634169600, 1634256000, 1634342400, 1634428800, 
1634515200, 1634601600, 1634688000, 1634774400, 1634860800, 1634947200, 
1635033600, 1635120000, 1635206400, 1635292800, 1635379200, 1635465600, 
1635552000, 1635638400, 1633392000, 1633478400, 1633564800, 1633651200, 
1633737600, 1633824000, 1633910400, 1633996800, 1634083200, 1634169600, 
1634256000, 1634342400, 1634428800, 1634515200, 1634601600, 1634688000, 
1634774400, 1634860800, 1634947200, 1635033600, 1635120000, 1635206400, 
1635292800, 1635379200, 1635465600, 1635552000, 1635638400, 1633392000, 
1633478400, 1633564800, 1633651200, 1633737600, 1633824000, 1633910400, 
1633996800, 1634083200, 1634169600, 1634256000, 1634342400, 1634428800, 
1634515200, 1634601600, 1634688000, 1634774400, 1634860800, 1634947200, 
1635033600, 1635120000, 1635206400, 1635292800, 1635379200, 1635465600, 
1635552000, 1635638400, 1633392000, 1633478400, 1633564800, 1633651200, 
1633737600, 1633824000, 1633910400, 1633996800, 1634083200, 1634169600, 
1634256000, 1634342400, 1634428800, 1634515200, 1634601600, 1634688000, 
1634774400, 1634860800, 1634947200, 1635033600, 1635120000, 1635206400, 
1635292800, 1635379200, 1635465600, 1635552000, 1635638400, 1633392000, 
1633478400, 1633564800, 1633651200, 1633737600, 1633824000, 1633910400, 
1633996800, 1634083200, 1634169600, 1634256000, 1634342400, 1634428800, 
1634515200, 1634601600, 1634688000, 1634774400, 1634860800, 1634947200, 
1635033600, 1635120000, 1635206400, 1635292800, 1635379200, 1635465600, 
1635552000, 1635638400, 1633392000, 1633478400, 1633564800, 1633651200, 
1633737600, 1633824000, 1633910400, 1633996800, 1634083200, 1634169600, 
1634256000, 1634342400, 1634428800, 1634515200, 1634601600, 1634688000, 
1634774400, 1634860800, 1634947200, 1635033600, 1635120000, 1635206400, 
1635292800, 1635379200, 1635465600, 1635552000, 1635638400, 1633392000, 
1633478400, 1633564800, 1633651200, 1633737600, 1633824000, 1633910400, 
1633996800, 1634083200, 1634169600, 1634256000, 1634342400, 1634428800, 
1634515200, 1634601600, 1634688000, 1634774400, 1634860800, 1634947200, 
1635033600, 1635120000, 1635206400, 1635292800, 1635379200, 1635465600, 
1635552000, 1635638400, 1633392000, 1633478400, 1633564800, 1633651200, 
1633737600, 1633824000, 1633910400, 1633996800, 1634083200, 1634169600, 
1634256000, 1634342400, 1634428800, 1634515200, 1634601600, 1634688000, 
1634774400, 1634860800, 1634947200, 1635033600, 1635120000, 1635206400, 
1635292800, 1635379200, 1635465600, 1635552000, 1635638400, 1633392000, 
1633478400, 1633564800, 1633651200, 1633737600, 1633824000, 1633910400, 
1633996800, 1634083200, 1634169600, 1634256000, 1634342400, 1634428800, 
1634515200, 1634601600, 1634688000, 1634774400, 1634860800, 1634947200, 
1635033600, 1635120000, 1635206400, 1635292800, 1635379200, 1635465600, 
1635552000, 1635638400, 1633392000, 1633478400, 1633564800, 1633651200, 
1633737600, 1633824000, 1633910400, 1633996800, 1634083200, 1634169600, 
1634256000, 1634342400, 1634428800, 1634515200, 1634601600, 1634688000, 
1634774400, 1634860800, 1634947200, 1635033600, 1635120000, 1635206400, 
1635292800, 1635379200, 1635465600, 1635552000, 1635638400, 1633392000, 
1633478400, 1633564800, 1633651200, 1633737600, 1633824000, 1633910400, 
1633996800, 1634083200, 1634169600, 1634256000, 1634342400, 1634428800, 
1634515200, 1634601600, 1634688000, 1634774400, 1634860800, 1634947200, 
1635033600, 1635120000, 1635206400, 1635292800, 1635379200, 1635465600, 
1635552000, 1635638400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Proporsi = c(0.148500365764448, 0.155075939248601, 
0.166821994408201, 0.200239808153477, 0.210322580645161, 0.221628838451268, 
0.245283018867925, 0.250853242320819, 0.222826086956522, 0.30859375, 
0.338297872340426, 0.316901408450704, 0.372037914691943, 0.367875647668394, 
0.451104100946372, 0.546938775510204, 0.533632286995516, 0.516279069767442, 
0.428571428571429, 0.615384615384615, 0.617801047120419, 0.556179775280899, 
0.585798816568047, 0.389937106918239, 0.705479452054795, 0.830769230769231, 
0.888888888888889, 0.483547925608011, 0.448795180722892, 0.464462809917355, 
0.477508650519031, 0.462522851919561, 0.453667953667954, 0.533477321814255, 
0.591346153846154, 0.55050505050505, 0.551724137931034, 0.611111111111111, 
0.612582781456954, 0.675409836065574, 0.726235741444867, 0.82824427480916, 
0.778625954198473, 0.839662447257384, 0.990654205607477, 0.917948717948718, 
0.936507936507937, 1.14838709677419, 1.26760563380282, 1.1203007518797, 
1.33644859813084, 1.52083333333333, 1.6304347826087, 1.46875, 
0.154362416107383, 0.141891891891892, 0.132275132275132, 0.14962962962963, 
0.153030303030303, 0.163779527559055, 0.165605095541401, 0.138041733547352, 
0.135514018691589, 0.135258358662614, 0.133834586466165, 0.138686131386861, 
0.13543599257885, 0.138632162661738, 0.143897996357013, 0.172335600907029, 
0.173027989821883, 0.161458333333333, 0.145780051150895, 0.211538461538462, 
0.226053639846743, 0.285714285714286, 0.225806451612903, 0.221789883268482, 
0.194756554307116, 0.189922480620155, 0.195571955719557, 0.230769230769231, 
0.231578947368421, 0.345238095238095, 0.24, 0.220779220779221, 
0.233766233766234, 0.208333333333333, 0.267605633802817, 0.277777777777778, 
0.3125, 0.216216216216216, 0.197183098591549, 0.208333333333333, 
0.208333333333333, 0.26865671641791, 0.264705882352941, 0.323529411764706, 
0.348484848484849, 0.212121212121212, 0.149253731343284, 0.208955223880597, 
0.258064516129032, 0.1875, 0.15625, 0.171875, 0.171875, 0.171875, 
0.243654822335025, 0.238565022421525, 0.228383458646617, 0.226874391431353, 
0.200205338809035, 0.190782422293676, 0.209919261822376, 0.192401960784314, 
0.191157347204161, 0.207520891364903, 0.199391171993912, 0.242375601926164, 
0.276632302405498, 0.305400372439479, 0.330693069306931, 0.324435318275154, 
0.34341252699784, 0.330357142857143, 0.309352517985612, 0.392592592592593, 
0.355329949238579, 0.380829015544041, 0.380952380952381, 0.330601092896175, 
0.3359375, 0.282776349614396, 0.360824742268041, 0.69305724725944, 
0.681953543776057, 0.64661214953271, 0.68118572292801, 0.422915416916617, 
0.426182237600923, 0.489071038251366, 0.564325177584846, 0.534277198211624, 
0.489705882352941, 0.432394366197183, 0.474926253687316, 0.479734708916728, 
0.522831050228311, 0.51386748844376, 0.526771653543307, 0.529411764705882, 
0.516984258492129, 0.523975588491718, 0.532637075718016, 0.573308270676692, 
0.678532901833873, 0.690744920993228, 0.637139807897545, 0.61522633744856, 
0.590465872156013, 0.574712643678161, 0.0579710144927536, 0.0882352941176471, 
0.19047619047619, 0.142857142857143, 0.0476190476190476, 0.0869565217391304, 
0.130434782608696, 0.12, 0.185185185185185, 0.166666666666667, 
0.142857142857143, 0.032258064516129, 0, 0.0238095238095238, 
0.0666666666666667, 0.0869565217391304, 0.0638297872340425, 0.0377358490566038, 
0.0196078431372549, 0.037037037037037, 0.0166666666666667, 0, 
0, 0.0344827586206897, 0.0338983050847458, 0.0344827586206897, 
0.0689655172413793, 0.156976744186047, 0.126801152737752, 0.115044247787611, 
0.115727002967359, 0.107361963190184, 0.13, 0.127208480565371, 
0.116541353383459, 0.125984251968504, 0.122362869198312, 0.0956521739130435, 
0.103139013452915, 0.140625, 0.144736842105263, 0.227642276422764, 
0.273684210526316, 0.227272727272727, 0.246753246753247, 0.287671232876712, 
0.289473684210526, 0.276923076923077, 0.288461538461538, 0.3, 
0.26, 0.297872340425532, 0.297872340425532, 0.272727272727273, 
0.268315445636958, 0.271113243761996, 0.256658595641647, 0.225711481844946, 
0.227474150664697, 0.229614807403702, 0.239833159541189, 0.249733759318424, 
0.241122565864834, 0.235055136390017, 0.244874048037493, 0.211981566820276, 
0.207656612529002, 0.211714460036608, 0.228842247799594, 0.232904536222072, 
0.256134969325153, 0.276629570747218, 0.274821286735504, 0.268691588785047, 
0.298230834035383, 0.281067556296914, 0.261344537815126, 0.25604670558799, 
0.243498817966903, 0.211482558139535, 0.208860759493671, 0.145617667356798, 
0.137005163511188, 0.138736263736264, 0.131660364386387, 0.133039945836154, 
0.125634947511006, 0.124826147426982, 0.120970537261698, 0.153423499577346, 
0.144299537231805, 0.138256762559038, 0.144809910294746, 0.154576856649396, 
0.169515011547344, 0.166277440448389, 0.16196205460435, 0.169491525423729, 
0.156326331216414, 0.162421912542047, 0.160140562248996, 0.165185572399373, 
0.162790697674419, 0.148958333333333, 0.151090342679128, 0.142406726221755, 
0.131509731720147, 0.122567069963177, 0.641673243883189, 0.624897624897625, 
0.669298245614035, 0.674053554939982, 0.665053242981607, 0.650793650793651, 
0.745119305856833, 0.747816593886463, 0.743243243243243, 0.795053003533569, 
0.815889029003783, 0.818543046357616, 0.847856154910097, 0.956456456456456, 
0.898773006134969, 0.861325115562404, 0.856910569105691, 0.911917098445596, 
0.887563884156729, 0.869718309859155, 0.958254269449715, 1.01803607214429, 
1.07392197125257, 0.979209979209979, 0.974576271186441, 0.943396226415094, 
0.927194860813705)), row.names = c(NA, -297L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code is not reproducible as your data has no column called `Date`. To set the colors your could try with `aes(..., color = case_when(Proporsi >= 0.4 ~ "RED", Proporsi <= 0.2 ~ "GREEN", TRUE ~ "Yellow"))` instead of `if ... else`.

Comment: @stefan thank you, I missed the date column and had edited it in. The code allowed for each segment of the line graph colored differently. But I'm aiming for the whole line to be colored depending on the latest value of the y-axis. Much appreciated if you have a workaround this! Thank youu!

Answer (score 0):

One option to color the lines based on the last value is to add a column to your dataframe which contains the last value for each group and could be used to set the color. To get the right colors you have to make use of `scale_color_manual`. I wasn't sure about how you want to place the label. In my opinion it's not absolutely necessary to make use of `ggrepel`. Instead I made use of `geom_text` to place the labels on the right of the last data point. To this end I increased the expansion of the x scale to make room for the labels. But feel free to switch to `ggrepel`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mydata <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(Provinsi) %>% 
  mutate(
    Proporsi_last = last(Proporsi),
    color = case_when(Proporsi_last >= 0.4 ~ "RED", Proporsi_last <= 0.2 ~ "GREEN", TRUE ~ "YELLOW")
  )

mydata_ends <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(Provinsi) %>% 
  top_n(1, Date)

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = Date, y = Proporsi, color = color)) +
  xlab("Tanggal") +
  ylab("Proporsi Keterisian TT/Kasus Aktif") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accurracy = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(RED = "red", GREEN = "green", YELLOW = "yellow")) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Proporsi)), data = mydata_ends, size = 3, hjust = -.1, color = "black") +
  scale_x_datetime(expand = expansion(mult = c(.05, .4))) +
  facet_wrap(~Provinsi, ncol = 4) +
  ggtitle("Proporsi KeterisianTT/Kasus Aktif") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", face = "bold", size = 20, hjust = 0, color = "#555555")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]